# how to retrieve field collection data associated with a node

Tags: entities

I have an event node which contains a reference to a gallery field collection. If I do a dump of the $variables variable, I can find this

```
$variables -> field_gallery_image['und'][0]['value']
```

but I don't know where to use that value to do a table look up to actually find the data in the field collection. I was able to find that id number in the field_collection_item table, and then was able to find that id in the field_data_field_image table (I have an image field), but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Where do you want to use this value? In `node.tpl.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for field_collection_item_load or field_collection_item_load_multiple function both are in field_collection.module

Comment: can those functions be called from inside of the theme template, or do I need a custom module? I want to be able to use the data for display purposes.

Comment: That did it, thanks! I used that function in a custom block.